# django-rest-allauth getting social token

Tags: django-rest-framework, google-oauth, django-allauth

First of all, sorry if this has been asked before, I cant find anything adapted to my low level.
I´m trying to use django-rest-allauth 1.1, which is cool it provides a fast basic endpoints building, though some tare found like email validation (if email login, it is made by username up to the @, so it´s done if email is edited or different username initially provided with email, so it just doesnt work email login...)
My question is about social login... How can i get Google´s token if developing a non front-end API?
I mean where is the google´s consent screen on the API?
Should I reformat allauth code to run django-rest-allauth social login right after consent call?
How can I achieve that?
Again, sorry my low level in both, english and programming skills.
Thanks